# Using MySQL's IN statement in Java

Tags: java, mysql, arrays

I have to find out if there are entries in a table that also exist in a list I have in Java. The logical solution would be "SELECT column FROM table WHERE column IN (?)" and then set ? to the array I have in Java, but setArray asks for a java.sql.Array and I'm not really sure how to obtain one and if it really is what I am looking for.

Comment: What API do you use to access DB? What `setArray` method is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with JDBC but if are using spring or hibernate, both have support for rewriting a query to unroll a list of parameters into the right number of ?.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select x from y where z in (:params)");
query.setParameterList("params", paramList);
List list = query.list();
```

In spring you need to use the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.

Comment: Nope, Spring won't do it, either.

Comment: @duffymo: Spring does: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-in-clause

Comment: Thank you for the correction axtavt - I haven't digested Spring 3.x yet.

Comment: I'd wonder if you looked at the Spring 3.x source code that it'd be doing exactly what I suggested.  Spring is just "syntactic sugar" in this case; it can only be done easily if the JDBC driver supports it.  Has there been a change to JDBC to make this possible?

Comment: @duffymo: Spring is rewriting the query.  The NamedParamJdbcTemplate supports hibernate style named parameters (:params) which it rewrites to ? internally.  Much like hibernate it can detect that a parameter is actually a Collection/array and unroll :params -> (?, ?, ? ... ?)  JDBC has no support for this, tho it would be nice.

Comment: Correct - "rewrites internally".  So it's not possible to do it without unrolling.

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not possible.

Unfortunately, IN requires two steps:

1. Add one binding `?` for each value.
2. Loop over the values and bind them to the `?`

No easy way to do it.

Comment: I'd ask everyone who downvotes my answer to try the jGuru solution and see if it really works. If it fails, come back and up vote mine.

Comment: Yes please, if the jGuru method fails or is notapplicable here, I'll delete my answer. Can't test it myself, unfortunately.

Comment: This is the only way.  I'll test it tonight to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the parameters are all generated by your program logic, i.e. there is no risk of a SQL injection, then I think it's okay to resort to good old string manipulation...

```
String status = "'Pending','Approved'";
String sql  = "SELECT * FROM table ";
       sql += "WHERE status IN (" + status + ")";
ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
```

If the parameters are in any way generated by user input, this opens you up to SQL injection. But if you control the parameters in your app code, I don't see a problem with it.

If passing from an array, make sure you wrap each parameter with quotes as you build the parameter string.

Simplest solution is usually better.